# How can we do passthrough physical disk partition to multipass virtual machine?

Tags: disk, multipass

I am setting up a Kubernetes cluster over multipass virtual machines for a test environment. We need access to raw harddisks within the virtual machines.

How can we connect physical disk partitions to multipass virtual machines?